# How to get the data from two models from user input?

Tags: python, django-models, django-views

The problem is that I can not go this model who believes has in particular that the user will assign many inputs to the model and those many I assign only one input to another model.

the idea is to get all data from all entries, each entry to get the last level related model, please see the example:

```
class User
    # a standard django.contrib.auth user model

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # my AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE for django-profiles
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    instance = models.ManyToManyField(Instance1)

class Model2(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    item0 = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    model2 = models.OneToOneField(Model2)

class Model3(models.Model):
    item1 = models.CharField(max_length=12)

user = request.user
```

Model2 - item1

- item0[0]= 1
- item0[1]= 2
- item0[2]= 3

Model3 - item2

- item1[0]= 4
- item1[1]= 5
- item1[2]= 6

as I can get the all item1 and intem2 form Model2 and Model3, using profile and placed in a variable to render in the template all the ManyToManyField -> (OneToOneField -> Items) ?

I'm trying:

```
myuser = request.user
items = UserProfile.objects.get(user=myuser)
```

go climbing the query.

Comment: You really need to work on the question - it is hard to say what is being asked here.

Comment: All right, I think I'm starting to get it - what have you tried so far in the template?

Comment: {% for item in allitem %}<p>{{item}}</p>{% endfor %}, that's the idea, <p>1</p> <p>2</p> <p>3</p> |apart| <p>4</p> <p>5</p> <p>6</p>

Comment: With this (UserProfile.objects.get (user = myuser)) I have all the data for that user, I only need to enter each of the ManyToManyField and get all the data, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be confusing models and instances. Everything you've defined here is just a blueprint, or a template - you don't really store or access data directly through them. You can, however, use them to give structure to your data, and to create *instances* of this structure.

For example, here I have defined a basic model. In Django, these are usually defined in `models.py`

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  element = models.CharField(max_length=12)
```

Now, I'll create *instances* of the model, using a function called a constructor. Generally speaking, you call it using just the name of the model (`ModelName(parameter=value,...)`). In Django, this is usually done as part of an action in `views.py`, but you can also try it out in the Python console by importing the class you need (`from models import Model`).

Here I populate 10 instances of `MyModel`:

```
for i in range (0,10):
  m = MyModel(element="letter" + str(i), name="Instance"+ str(i))
  m.save() # this saves m in MyModel.objects
```

All of these instances are accessed through `ModelName.objects.all()`, from which you can access the field via the usual `.` notation:

```
models = MyModel.objects.all()
output = ""
for m in models:
  output += m.name + ":" + m.element
```

Taking this and outputting it to your browser takes a few more steps - I'd highly recommend trying out the [official Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/), step-by-step, to gain a better understanding of how the framework works.

Comment: instance and the item was only for the example, the model is well defined user model to model2 and model3, what you want is to get the data from the two models from user input, I'll edit the question to not confuciones fall.